# EXC_BAD_ACCES error when trying to create a string like "test%40test.nl"

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

Can someone explain this behaviour and how to get past this? I can't find anything related.

```
// everything is fine
var test1 = "String without percentage";
NSLog(test1);

// fine
var test2 = "String with percentage %";
NSLog(test2);

// fine
var test3 = "test@test.nl";
NSLog(test3);

// still fine
var test4 = "%";
NSLog(test4);

var test5 = "test%40test.nl";
NSLog(test5); // error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

I can actually see and print the string in the debug window but I keep getting the error when I try to use the variabele in code.

```
test5   String  "test%40test.nl"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSLog` uses % as the string interpolation character (à la printf). If you want to print a percentage sign you need to quote it with %%.

```
NSLog(@"Here's a percent sign: %%");
```

The reason it's crashing, is (I think) that it's expecting %t (ptrdiff_t) with field width of 40. You're passing no extra parameters and hence `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Answer (score 0):

To print `%` you need: `"%%"`

```
var test5 = "test%%40test.nl";
NSLog(test5);
```